# Error at scrapy: incomplete format at using forms and tables

Tags: python, forms, csv, scrapy

I'm having an error that I can't solve by myself. I want to scrapy the first column of the table when you post the "PARTIDO POLITICO" in the form.

I done this code:

```
from scrapy.spiders import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.http import FormRequest, Request

class PoliticItem(scrapy.Item):
    politic_party = scrapy.Field()

class PoliticSpider(BaseSpider):

    name = "PoliticSpider"
    allowed_domains = ["servicio.mir.es"]
    start_urls = ['https://servicio.mir.es/nfrontal/webpartido_politico.html?pagActual=%' % page for page in xrange(1,189)] 
    def parse(self, response):
        yield FormRequest.from_response(response, formdata={'tipoFormacion':'P','ordenacion':'DENOMINACION'}, callback=self.parse_table)
    def parse_table(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        rows = hxs.select('//table[@id="resultado"]')
        items = []
        for row in rows:
            item = PoliticItem()
            item['partido_politico'] = annonce.select('td[1]/a/text()').extract()
            items.append(item)
        return items
```

But I still got a error when I run:

```
scrapy runspider gobierno.py -o data.csv -t csv


2016-03-08 12:22:35 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.5 started (bot: scrapybot)  
2016-03-08 12:22:35 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11  
2016-03-08 12:22:35 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv', 'FEED_URI': 'data.csv'}  
Usage  
=====  
  scrapy runspider [options] <spider_file>  

runspider: error: Unable to load 'gobierno.py': incomplete format
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in **start_urls** format.
You need to specify the format code after **%**, like:

```
'hello %s' % 'world'
```

To your case, should be:

```
start_urls = ['https://servicio.mir.es/nfrontal/webpartido_politico.html?pagActual=%d' % page for page in xrange(1,189)]
```

You can see the complete code list in https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language

Comment: Thanks! i correct that but im having exactly the same error at the console :/